# Python backreference replacing doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, regex, replace

There are two named groups in my pattern: **myFlag** and **id**, I want to add one more **myFlag** immediately before group **id**.

Here is my current code:

```
# i'm using Python 3.4.2
import re
import os
contents = b'''
xdlg::xdlg(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)
    : customized_dlg((UINT)0, pParent, pApp)
    , m_pReaderApp(pApp)
    , m_info(pApp)
{

}
'''

pattern = rb'(?P<myFlag>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)::(?P=myFlag).+:.+(?P<id>\(UINT\)0 *,)'
res = re.search(pattern, contents, re.DOTALL)
if None != res:
    print(res.groups()) # the output is (b'xdlg', b'(UINT)0,')

# 'replPattern' becomes b'(?P<myFlag>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)::(?P=myFlag).+:.+((?P=myFlag)\\(UINT\\)0 *,)'
replPattern = pattern.replace(b'?P<id>', b'(?P=myFlag)', re.DOTALL)
print(replPattern)
contents = re.sub(pattern, replPattern, contents)
print(contents)
```

The expected results should be:

```
xdlg::xdlg(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)
    : customized_dlg(xdlg(UINT)0, pParent, pApp)
    , m_pReaderApp(pApp)
    , m_info(pApp)
{

}
```

but now the result this the same with the original:

```
 xdlg::xdlg(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)
    : customized_dlg((UINT)0, pParent, pApp)
    , m_pReaderApp(pApp)
    , m_info(pApp)
{

}
```

Comment: Why are you replacing `?P<id>` (no parens) with `(?P=myFlag)` (with parens)?

Comment: Besides, there is no third `xdlg` string in the input. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: because I want to replace the string with 'myFlag' group, it's a must to encloe them with parens(python syntax)

Comment: What is the *expected* output here? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You replaced the name of a named group with a back reference, the regex syntax makes no sense here.

Comment: Wow, there is so much wrong here ... the reason the output isn't changing is because you aren't passing `flags=re.DOTALL` to `re.sub`, but your replacement string doesn't make sense at *all*. Does python regex syntax support something equivalent to vim's `\zs` and `\ze` ?

Comment: @o11c, thank you for your advice. but with 're.DOTALL', it still doesn't work, i have no knowledge of VIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be the pattern syntax — particularly the end:

`0 *,)`

That makes no sense really... fixing it seems to solve most of the issues, although I would recommend ditching `DOTALL` and going with `MULTILINE` instead:

```
p = re.compile(ur'([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)::\1(.*\n\W+:.*)(\(UINT\)0,.*)', re.MULTILINE)
sub = u"\\1::\\1\\2\\1\\3"
result = re.sub(p, sub, s)

print(result)
```

**Result:**

```
xdlg::xdlg(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)
    : customized_dlg(xdlg(UINT)0, pParent, pApp)
    , m_pReaderApp(pApp)
    , m_info(pApp)
{

}
```

https://regex101.com/r/hG3lV7/1

Comment: i had tried your pattern, it did work. however, i'm confused, is it necessary to introduce 5 groups? is it possbile to solve this issue with 2 groups?

Comment: No five groups aren't necessary (see edit), although I couldn't entirely make sense of the ones you had either. In my opinion named groups in `Python` are somewhat worthless unless you have many groups that you need to keep track of across multiple replacements, etc. Otherwise it's just more code that essentially makes things more confusing.

Comment: It's not necessary, so remove it. I think the pattern can be further improved too — the answer in this instance was to mainly to illustrate what the issue was for it not working.

Comment: how can I achieve the same effect with re.DOTALL?

Comment: `re.DOTALL` should work with the pattern above (still using three capture groups), although could be simplified to be something like `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)::\1(.*)(\(UINT\)0,.*)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83063/discussion-between-oskywalker-and-lll).